# XSLT Caching Issue

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, saxon

I am trying to implement a cache for XSL in C#.  I have implemented following code

```
   Xsl2Processor xsl = new Xsl2Processor();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("xsl_" + xslPath) == null)
        {
            xsl.Load(xslPath);
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("xsl_" + xslPath, xsl, new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(xslPath));
        }
        else
        {
            xsl = (Xsl2Processor)HttpContext.Current.Cache.Get("xsl_" + xslPath);
        }
        return xsl;
```

It's working fine for single User ID.  When I am trying for two User ID simultaneous(Load Test).  Data of Users getting Switched.  Why this happened and what would be the solution?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that is causing the issue? The code sample shown does not include any "UserID", for example. Additionally, if data is getting switched, then that is more likely to be an issue with the XML, not the XSLT. Thanks.

Comment: Code without Cache is working good,with Cache cause the problem.when  simultaneous run for different User,value are switch between in Output Xml.

Comment: What is `Xsl2Processor`? Is that your own class?

Comment: Hi Martin..Xsl2Processor is class provided by Saxon.

Comment: No, that's not correct, it's not provided by Saxon (or Saxonica). It's part of a project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24766/XSL-and-XQuery-in-NET developed by a third party.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the correction,its SAXON 9.0.0.2 from Saxonica

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to answer this without knowing what your `Xsl2Processor` class is. But in Saxon terms, the `XsltExecutable` is a thread-safe representation of the compiled stylesheet which you can safely cache, while the `XsltTransformer` (the result of calling `Load()`) is intended to be used once only - you can use it to run multiple transformations one after the other (though there's no benefit in doing so), but you cannot use it to run multiple transformations concurrently. The object you should be caching is the `XsltExecutable`.

You've also shown no evidence that your cache logic is properly synchronized to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Xsl2Processor  is SaxonWrapper (Saxon Processor-v2.0.50727)

Comment: I'm not prepared to download that project and study the source code. Please let us know what Saxon.Api objects are encapsulated by the Xsl2Processor.